# How to aggregate a MongoDB query to remove the usage of a for loop?

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregate

I am new to MongoDB and am working with it on NodeJS code.

As you can see the below code, I am running a for loop through my books collection to figure out the latest version of the `query_book`.

I know that this isn't efficient, and want to understand how can an aggregation function be written for it in MongoDB.

Current code:

```
let result= {};
_.forEach(books, function(query_book)
{
   if(!result[query_book.book_id])
   {
     result[query_book.book_id] = query_book
   }
   else if(result[query_book.book_id].book_version < 
            query_book.book_version)
   {
     result[query_book.book_id] = query_book
   }
```

Data Object for `books`:

```
[
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Sam”,
    “name”: “Sample Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Martin",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Roy",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  }
]

[
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "0”,
    "author": “Don”,
    “name”: “Another Book”,
    “comments”: “Done”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "1",
    "author": "Ray",
    "name": "Another Book",
    “comments”: “In Progress”
  },
  {
    "book_id": "bcj123n”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Max",
    "name": "Another Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  }
]
```

In this case, I want to fetch the object having the maximum value of `book_version` for my input `book_id` which is `ab12nld`:

```
{
    "book_id": "ab12nld”,
    "book_version": "2",
    "author": "Roy",
    "name": "Sample Book",
    “comments”: “To-Do”
  }
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your for loop, you don't seem to be using `i`. Maybe post your desired input & output or update that loop to work.

Comment: @thomasin: I have edited the loop and added the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Node.js Mongo driver (replace `[bookId]` with your input)

```
db.collection('books')
  .findOne({ book_id: [bookId] }, { sort: [['book_version', -1]] })
```

Or, if using Mongoose,

```
Book.findOne({ book_id: [bookId] }).sort({ book_version: -1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.books.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "book_version": -1 } },{"$limit":1}])
```

Comment: I wanted to fetch the highest book_version of the book_id which I would input. How can I do the same as part of this query?

Comment: db.books.aggregate([{"$match":{"book_id": "ab12nld"}},{ "$sort": { "book_version": -1 } },{"$limit":1}])

Comment: db.books.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$book_version","obj":{ "$push": "$$ROOT"  }}},{$sort:{_id:-1}},{$limit:1}]) .  result will look like - { "_id" : "7", "obj" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5*.."), "book_id" : "ab12nld-best", "book_version" : "7", "author" : "Roy", "name" : "Sample Book the best one", "comments" : "To-Do" } ] }

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to retrieve a document having highest value of a field.

Here, the document having the highest value in the `version` field. The simplest way of doing this is to `sort` in reverse order and get the first document.

You can also use the aggregate method.

Try the following snippet. I think it will help.

```
db.books.find().sort({"book_version":-1}).limit(1);
```

Comment: I wanted to fetch the highest book_version of the book_id which I would input. How can I do the same as part of this query?

Comment: Try:         db.books.find({"book_id":"abcd"}).sort({"book_version":-1}).limit(1);